# SSLError when using google api client library

Tags: python, google-api-python-client

I'm using google api client library on a Ubuntu server. While the script works fine on my own machine, on the server it fails with SSLError:

```
File "/home/default/bigbluebutton/youtube/uploader/uploadvideo.py", line 78, in authorize
    credentials = flow.step2_exchange(code)        
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2client/util.py", line 132, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2client/client.py", line 1283, in step2_exchange
    headers=headers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1570, in request
    (response, content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1317, in _request
    (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1252, in _conn_request
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1021, in connect
    self.disable_ssl_certificate_validation, self.ca_certs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 80, in _ssl_wrap_socket
    cert_reqs=cert_reqs, ca_certs=ca_certs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 381, in wrap_socket
    ciphers=ciphers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 141, in __init__
    ciphers)
ssl.SSLError: [Errno 185090050] _ssl.c:340: error:0B084002:x509 certificate routines:X509_load_cert_crl_file:system lib
```

How to fix this problem? Is it something wrong with SSL?

Comment: The info here might help you out: https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/557

Comment: I tried but it doesn't help. The server is Ubuntu 12.04, the same as m development machine.

Comment: What solutions from that link did you try?

Answer (score 1):

The solution that works for me is changing permission of cacerts.txt to your own user (instead of root). Or run as root. You can find the files at /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2/cacerts.txt

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue , The reason I guess is because the appropriate certificate could not be loaded.
Below is the code snippet from httplib2/**init**.py, which loads the certificate.

```
    try:
        # Users can optionally provide a module that tells us where the CA_CERTS
        # are located.
        import ca_certs_locater
        CA_CERTS = ca_certs_locater.get()
    except ImportError:
        # Default CA certificates file bundled with httplib2.
        CA_CERTS = os.path.join(
            os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__ )), "cacerts.txt")
```

httplib2/**init**.py Location :/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2-0.8-py2.7.egg/httplib2/**init**.py

In the above code ca_certs_locater loads the certificate authority file from the base OS instead of the one in the httplib2 package.
If the [ca_certs_locater](https://github.com/dreamhost/httplib2-ca_certs_locater) module does not exist it loads the certificate from the the file cacerts.txt.

In my case the module was not present, so it was loading from file "cacerts.txt", which i was not sure if present or not.I fixed this issue by installing the module, [ca_certs_locater](https://github.com/dreamhost/httplib2-ca_certs_locater).